# Meaning of Molecular Oxygen

Tags: physical-chemistry, nomenclature, terminology

Does molecular oxygen just mean the oxygen molecule? Or could it refer to a certain state of the molecule (eg. gas or aqueous)?

Answer (score 1):

Molecular Oxygen means that it's bonded to another Oxygen (O2). Atomic oxygen would just give you O.